# Linq To Sql Multiple Where Search In Foreach Loop

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, search, foreach, where-clause

I'm trying to filter a table using where clause. When I the write the queries separately they work fine:

```
IQueryable<Movie> movies = db.Movies;
movies = movies.Where(movie =>
    movie.MovieToGenres.Any(genreItem => genreItem.Genre_ID == 34)
);
movies = movies.Where(movie =>
    movie.MovieToGenres.Any(genreItem => genreItem.Genre_ID == 35)
);
```

However I have to use it in a `foreach` loop:

```
List<int> genre_ids = new List<int>();
genre_ids.Add(34);
genre_ids.Add(35);

IQueryable<Movie> movies = db.Movies;
foreach (var genre_id in genre_ids)
{
   movies = movies.Where(movie =>
       movie.MovieToGenres.Any(genreItem => genreItem.Genre_ID == genre_id)
   );
}
```

When I do that, on the SQL side the query parameters are `@p0 = 35`, `@p1 = 35` instead of `@p0 = 34`, `@p1 = 35`. I don't know why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's another case of [capturing the loop variable](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx). There's only one `genre_id` variable which is captured by all the lambda expressions. It's easy to fix by introducing a new variable on each iteration, and capture that instead:

```
foreach (var genre_id in genre_ids)
{
   int genreCopy = genre_id;
   movies = movies.Where(movie => movie.MovieToGenres.Any(
                  genreItem => genreItem.Genre_ID == genreCopy));
}
```

In C# 5 this may be unnecessary - the behaviour may well be changing.

Comment: +1 "In C# 5 this may be unnecessary - the behaviour may well be changing." With the number of *access to modified closure* questions, let's hope so :)

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are looking something like this

```
List<int> genres = new List<int>() { 34, 35, 36 };
movies = movies.Where(movie => movie.MovieToGenres.Any(genreItem => genres.Contains(genreItem.Genre_ID));
```

it should translates to `IN ( 34, 35, 36)`